# Why does Rick attack Negan (comic version) in All Out War Part 2 (Volume 21)

Tags: comics, the-walking-dead

So in the end of this comic:

> Rick tries to convince Negan that his actions were horribly wrong, and that the communities should be working together. However, Rick then slits Negan's throat and tries to convince the two sides to work together.

Question:

> Did Negan actually believe Rick's plan for the communities working together, when he claimed something along the lines of "oh, I've doing this the wrong way this whole time" (and thus the slitting was only revenge for Negan's killings)? Or was it part of Negan's arrogant self just to trick Rick again?

Answer (score 3):

The question text and title seem to be asking two different things.  Was Negan genuine?  I think to some degree, yes.  In a previous comic he took out one of his own men for violating one of his rules of society by attempting a sexual assault.

> "What the fuck are we doing here?  What are we trying to achieve?!  For fuck's sake don't answer that either... there's no fucking way you have a goddamn clue what the bigger fucking picture is.  This war, however long it lasts... is a means to an end.  When the dust settles, and we've won... ultimately we have to work with these people!  We want a community that can accomplish things together!  That healing cannot begin if we have sunk to such in-fucking-human levels!  Repeat after me.  We. Don't. Rape."

It seems strange from someone who regularly beats people to death with baseball bats in front of their friends, but I think Negan really was trying to build a society, he just believed that it needed a strong warlord type at the head, a big bad to scare anybody else out of thinking they could just take over by force and be even worse.  And enjoying certain perks of that position, like having a harem, etc.  But he still felt he was building a society and he had own set of rules.    In many other situations he refused to go the violent route, or directed his violence towards untrustworthy "troublemakers" (like someone who tried to betray Rick to him) rather than people he could work with.  He threatened Eugene with mutilation, and said "I don't really want to do this... but I do things I don't want to do all the fucking time." And left him unharmed until his fear made him give the information.

Negan didn't see himself as a monster, he saw himself as playing a monster role.  To a certain extent he was arguably right... he built up a large set of followers, and towns working to a common goal, killing a few to keep everyone in line.  It was bloody and brutal like many primitive societies are, and good people died for nothing, but on the whole, in his eyes, it was working for him.  And I think he realized on some level that as the war kept escalating, he was getting worse and worse, but he was still telling himself it was a necessary evil for greater stability down the line.  And with Rick's final plea, I think he was genuinely seeing that he was messing it all up, that they could work together, if someone like Rick, who, after all that conflict, was still willing to work with him, they really could build a functional society on another basis.

So why did Rick attack?  Because he simply couldn't trust Negan, and he needed to send a message to his army that his behavior was unacceptable, that there were still consequences to behaving like a brutal warlord.